# Why does setInterval never run, in my NodeJs code that streams an generator to file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval, node-streams

I have this situation in my NodeJs code, which calculates permutations (code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70839805/1075247)), but no matter what I don't get any output from `setInterval`.

```js
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const { intervalToDuration, formatDuration, format } = require('date-fns');
const { subsetPerm } = require('./permutation');

function formatLogs(counter, permStart) {
    const newLocal = new Date();
    const streamTime = formatDuration(intervalToDuration({
        end: newLocal.getTime(),
        start: permStart.getTime()
    }));
    const formattedLogs = `wrote ${counter.toLocaleString()} patterns, after ${streamTime}`;
    return formattedLogs;
}

const ONE_MINUTES_IN_MS = 1 * 60 * 1000;

let progress = 0;
let timerCallCount = 1;
let start = new Date();
const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(formatLogs(progress, start));
}, ONE_MINUTES_IN_MS);

const iterStream = Readable.from(subsetPerm(Object.keys(Array.from({ length: 200 })), 5));

console.log(`Stream started on: ${format(start, 'PPPPpppp')}`)
iterStream.on('data', () => {
    progress++;
    if (new Date().getTime() - start.getTime() >= (ONE_MINUTES_IN_MS * timerCallCount)) {
        console.log(`manual timer: ${formatLogs(progress, start)}`)
        timerCallCount++;
        if (timerCallCount >= 3) iterStream.destroy();
    }
});

iterStream.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
    clearInterval(interval);
});

iterStream.on('close', () => {
    console.log(`closed: ${formatLogs(progress, start)}`);
    clearInterval(interval);
})

console.log('done!');
```

But what I find is that it prints 'done!' (expected) and then the script seems to end, even though if I put a console.log in my `on('data')` callback I get data printed to the terminal. But even hours later the console.log in the `setInterval` never runs, as nothing ends up on file, besides the output from the `on('close',...)`.

The output log looks like:

```
> node demo.js

Stream started on: Sunday, January 30th, 2022 at 5:40:50 PM GMT+00:00
done!
manual timer: wrote 24,722,912 patterns, after 1 minute
manual timer: wrote 49,503,623 patterns, after 2 minutes
closed: wrote 49,503,624 patterns, after 2 minutes
```

The timers in node guide has a section called '[leaving timeouts behind](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/#leaving-timeouts-behind)' which looked relevant. But where I though using `interval.ref();` told the script to not garbage collect the object until `.unref()` is called on the same timeout object, on second reading that's not quite right, and doesn't make a difference.

I'm running this using npm like so `npm run noodle` which just points to the file.

Comment: Streams are async so `done!` will always print first...

Comment: @VikasKeskar `setTimeOut` should also block exit. Does it print anything other from `close` event?

Comment: @pilchard yes, but nothing is printed even hours later

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA the close event does end up printing something

Comment: @AncientSwordRage that means `setInterval` gets `cleared` and don't get a chance to execute?

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA but the total time elapsed is much longer than the interval, i.e. it might take 3 hours to run, and the interval is ~10 minutes

Comment: @AncientSwordRage can you give something a simple prototype so that everyone can tinker? Otherwise difficult to debug.

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA I've updated, let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

### The generator is synchronous and blocks the event loop

[Readable.from](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/streams/from.js) processes the whole generator in one go, so if the generator is synchronous and long running it blocks the event loop.

Here is the annotated code that it runs:

```js
async function next() {
    for (;;) {
      try {
        const { value, done } = isAsync ?
          await iterator.next() : // our generator is not asynchronous
          iterator.next();

        if (done) {
          readable.push(null); // generator not done
        } else {
          const res = (value &&
            typeof value.then === 'function') ?
            await value :
            value; // not a thenable
          if (res === null) {
            reading = false;
            throw new ERR_STREAM_NULL_VALUES();
          } else if (readable.push(res)) { // readable.push returns false if it's been paused, or some other irrelevant cases.
            continue; // we continue to the next item in the iterator
          } else {
            reading = false;
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        readable.destroy(err);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
```

Here is the api for [readable.push](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablepushchunk-encoding), which explains how this keeps the generator running:

> Returns:  true if additional chunks of data may continue to be pushed; false otherwise.

Nothing has told NodeJs not to continue pushing data, so it carries on.

> Between each run of the event loop, Node.js checks if it is waiting for any asynchronous I/O or timers and shuts down cleanly if there are not any.

I raised this as a [NodeJs Github Issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/41821) and ended up workshopping this solution:

```js
cosnt yieldEvery = 1e5;

function setImmediatePromise() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
}

const iterStream = Readable.from(async function* () {
    let i = 0
    for await (const item of baseGenerator) {
        yield item;
        i++;
        if (i % yieldEvery === 0) await setImmediatePromise();
    }
}());
```

This is partly inspired by this [snyk.io blog](https://snyk.io/blog/nodejs-how-even-quick-async-functions-can-block-the-event-loop-starve-io/), which goes into more detail on this issue.